# Read json file from python

Tags: python, json, file

I am trying to read a json file from python script using the `json` module. After some googling I found the following code:

```
with open(json_folder+json) as json_file:
        json_data = json.loads(json_file)
        print(json_data)
```

Where `json_folder+json` are the path and the name of the json file. I am getting the following error:

```
str object has no attribute loads.
```

Comment: If json is a string with a filename, what do you want to achieve by calling loads on the string?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The code is using `json` as a variable name. It will shadow the module reference you imported. Use different name for the variable.

Beside that, the code is passing file object, while [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) accept a string.

Pass a file content:

```
json_data = json.loads(json_file.read())
```

or use [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) which accepts file-like object.

```
json_data = json.load(json_file)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
import json
f = open( "fileToOpen.json" , "rb" )
jsonObject = json.load(f)
f.close()
```

it should seems you are doing in rather complicated way.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the path to your json file is set to the variable `json_file`:

```
import json

with open(json_file, "rb") as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

print json_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :-

```
json_data=open(json_file)
data = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

I Make This....

```
import urllib2

link_json = "\\link-were\\"
link_open = urllib2.urlopen(link_json) ## Open and Return page.
link_read = link_open.read()           ## Read contains of page.

json = eval(link_read)[0]              ## Transform the string of read in link_read and return the primary dictionary ex: [{dict} <- return this] <- remove this

print(json['helloKey'])

Hello World
```

Comment: Not sure how this is relevant.