# Using Geospatial data in python

Tags: python, json

I'm doing a university project on some animmal distribution, and I need to create a Choroplet type map of Italy,  I tried to find some data about regions and I found this https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson/tree/master/countries/italy, it's exactyl what I need but I don't know how to import and use in python.
I downloaded it and use the line pd.read_json(r'Path') but it doesn't work.
Can tell me if it's possible using this type of data? Or I should make them by myself?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read json file from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178211/read-json-file-from-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a json file, so you will load it like this:

```
import json

with open('/path/to/your/italy-provinces.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print(data)
```

`data` is now a dictionary, you can access its values like this:

```
print(data.keys())
#dict_keys(['type', 'arcs', 'transform', 'objects'])
print(data['objects'])
```

[image]

The `objects` contains information about cities like name, arcs, etc. And the `arcs` contains coordinates of cities