# Website parsing using JSON file gives an JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a website and save the data in a JSON file. The parsing code works fine, where i can insert the url and get the correct information. However, when writing a loop that should take the page url's from a JSON file, it says JSONDecodeError: Expecting value. Does anyone have a clue to fix this.

The followig code is what i have tried:

```
import time
import json

content = open('Codes_test.json', 'r', encoding= 'UTF-8')
counter = 0

for line in content:
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter>5: break
        
    obj = json.loads(line)
    
    url = obj["page_url"]
    print(f'Retrieving data for {url}')
    
    retrieved_data = parse_website(url)
    
    f = open('page_content.json', 'a', encoding = 'utf-8')
    f.write(json.dumps(retrieved_data))
    f.write('\n')
    f.close() 

time.sleep(1)
```

The JSON file looks like this:

```
[
 {"page_url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3794354/parentalguide"},
 {"page_url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7713068/parentalguide"},
 {"page_url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0983946/parentalguide"},
 {"page_url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1502397/parentalguide"},
 {"page_url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7798646/parentalguide"}
]
```

Comment: This is not how you read or write JSON. Load the whole file, then iterate over resulting list of dicts. Writing the retrieved data (if JSON - we don't know what `parse_website` returns) is also problematic, unless you want ndjson

Comment: the first line of your file doesn't contain page_url

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26178257/3462319